# Is nodal analysis applicable to a circuit containing a DC and AC supply?

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc, inductor, nodal-analysis

I think I can solve it using superposition but I am wondering if the nodal analysis is applicable to a circuit containing both an AC and DC supply? I am having trouble with what frequency I should use to convert inductors and/or capacitors to their corresponding impedances in the frequency domain (i.e. what omega to plug-in in jwL and j/wC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am having trouble with what frequency I should use to convert inductors and/or capacitors to their corresponding impedances in the frequency domain (i.e. what omega to plug-in in jwL and j/wC).

If you are doing AC analysis (assuming the behavior is linear when driven by a small AC excitation around a DC operating point), then you will do two steps.

First solve for the DC operating point. For this step you treat AC voltage sources as short circuits and AC current sources as open circuits.

Then solve for the AC response. For this step you treat DC voltage sources as short circuits and DC current sources as open circuits.

When you re-combine the results from these two steps to get the complete circuit behavior, you are using the superposition principle.

Phasor analysis is only useful for the second step. You will use the frequency of the AC source as the frequency that determines the capacitor and inductor impedances. If there are multiple AC sources with different frequencies, then you have to solve for the response to each one separately, recalculating the impedances for each frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the frequency corresponding to the voltage source that you're computing the values for. That is, when you calculate the currents and voltage drops caused by the DC source, all capacitors are open-circuit and inductors are short-circuit. Then when you do the same for an AC source, you replace the caps and inductors with the impedance they have at the frequency of that AC source. If you have another AC source with a different frequency, you'll again have to use different impedances.

This is of course only possible as long as your system is linear and time-invariant (LTI), which is true for a circuit that consists only of resistors, inductors and capacitors.